# Как с помощью классов сделать простую цепочку?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Я хочу чтобы можно было работать с классами и их элементами например вот так:

```
animal->land animals->horse->getSex()
```

или

```
animal->underwater animals->whale->getAge()
```

или для понятия

```
животные->сухопутные->собака->какая-нибудь функция
```

Все это одно выражение

так как это можно реализовать с помощью классов?
не обязательно расписывать все от и до, достаточно просто объяснить как это сделать и все.
заранее покорнейше благодарю всех тех, кто ответит на мой вопрос.

Comment: А просто `static_cast<указатель предка>(базовый указатель)` не пробовали ?

Comment: Напоминает обращение по указателю. Например, заводим 3 класса для: `animal`, `land_animals` и `horse`. У `animal` добавляем поле как указатель на тип `land_animals`, у `land_animals` поле указатель на `horse`, а у `horse` создаем метод `getSex()`. После, в конструктора классов инициируем поля, создаем объект `animal` и можно вызвать такую цепочку

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что это имена? Классов? Объектов? И какова семантика такого доступа? О какой именно лошади идёт речь в `animal->land animals->horse->getSex()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напоминает обращение по указателю. Например, заводим 3 класса для: animal, land_animals и horse. У animal добавляем поле как указатель на тип land_animals, у land_animals поле указатель на horse, а у horse создаем метод getSex(). После, в конструктора классов инициируем поля, создаем объект animal и можно вызвать такую цепочку.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Horse {
    public:
        bool getSex() {
            return true;
        }
};

class LandAnimals {
    public:
        Horse* horse;

        LandAnimals() {
            horse = new Horse();
        }
        ~LandAnimals() {
            delete horse;
        }
};

class Animal {
    public:
        LandAnimals* land_animals;

        Animal() {
            land_animals = new LandAnimals();
        }
        ~Animal() {
            delete land_animals;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Animal* animal = new Animal();
    cout << "sex: " << animal->land_animals->horse->getSex();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Такая цепочка методов носит название Fluent interface. 
Ссылки по теме: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429631/c-builder-pattern-with-fluent-interface
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084503/whats-a-fluent-interface
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864311/how-to-implement-nested-fluent-interface

Comment: Напоминает шаблон проектирования Строитель :)